# How to install the latest GDAL version on RedHat Linux 8

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, python3

I am trying to install GDAL for a usage with Python 3.8.
I noticed that the library is not accessible via yum directly, you need to Install it through EPEL store.

```
dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y gdal
```

However it doesn't provide the latest version of GDAL.
Is there a better way to do this, using the latest version with a build from the source?

Answer (score 1):

The process is as followed:

- Meet build requirement

Typically on redhat, you will need to install PROJ: [requirements](https://gdal.org/build_hints.html#build-requirements)

```
yum -y install proj-devel
```

- Download & build from source

Select the version you are interested in, here I use 3.5.2

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.5.2/gdal-3.5.2rc1.tar.gz
tar zxvf gdal-3.5.2rc1.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.5.2/
mkdir build
./configure --with-python
make 
make install
```

Verify it is working with : `gdal-config --version`

- Tell python where to find gdal

Then to be able to use it python you need to set variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/app-root/lib/python3.8/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldconfig
```

You should then be able to finally test it with python:

`python -c 'from osgeo import gdal; print(gdal.__version__);'`